# Move-Item : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: windows, powershell

So I'm working on a script to move duplicate files from a given directory (Let's call it D:\Pictures) to the Duplicates subdirectory (D:\Pictures\Duplicates, in this case).

As it stands, the only visible issue I'm having is the actual act of moving the file from the source (D:\Pictures\ [picture]) to the destination (D:\Pictures\Duplicates\ [picture]). Move-Item returns with an error of "The given path's format is not supported".

The format used for the duplicate files is a simple renaming to the date in which the file was created, such as: D:\Pictures\Duplicates\5-6-2015 06:34:22PM.bmp

When I use direct filepaths, such as D:\Pictures\001 - Copy.bmp and D:\Pictures\Duplicates\5-6-2015 06:34:22PM.bmp respectively it works just fine, and only returns that error when the variables are used.

What I've got so far is as follows (Full code included for testing replication purposes):

```
cls
echo "Duplicate Sorter -- Version 1.0.0 Alpha"
echo "-------------------------------------"
echo "What directory do you want to sort?"
$workingDir = "false"
while ($workingDir -eq "false")
{
    $DIR = Read-Host
    if (($DIR -eq "C:\") -or ($DIR -like "C:\Program Files*") -or ($DIR -like "C:\Program Files(x86)*") -or ($DIR -like "C:\Windows*") -or ($DIR -like "C:\DRIVERS*") -or ($DIR -like "C:\SWTOOLS*") -or ($DIR -like "C:\inetpub*") -or ($DIR -like "C:\PerfLogs*"))
    {
        echo "You can't choose that directory. Choose a different one."   
    } 
    Else
    {
        $workingDir = "true"
    }
}
echo "What file type do you want to sort? (Press the relative number)"
echo "1. Pictures"
echo "2. Movies"
echo "3. GIFs"
echo "4. PNGs"
echo "5. Custom Type"
$workingType = "false"
while ($workingType -eq "false")
{
    $fileType = Read-Host
    if ($fileType -eq 1)
    {
        $fileType = "jpg"
        $workingType = "true"
    } 
    elseif ($fileType -eq 2)
    {
        $fileType = "avi"  
        $workingType = "true"
    }
    elseif ($fileType -eq 3)
    {
        #Pronounced with a hard G, not like Jif. Gifs aren't a brand of peanut butter!
        $fileType = "gif"
        $workingType = "true"
    } 
    elseif ($fileType -eq 4)
    {
        $fileType = "png"
        $workingType = "true"
    }
    elseif ($fileType -eq 5)
    {
        echo "Okay then, Mr. 'I'm special and deserve my own type', enter your custom type."
        $fileType = Read-Host
        $workingType = "true"
    }
    Else
    {
        echo "This is an invalid option. Try again."
    }
}
$mkdups = "$DIR\$fileType Duplicates"
if (!(Test-Path -Path $mkdups))
{
    New-Item $mkdups -ItemType directory  
}
$preList = Get-ChildItem "$DIR" -Recurse
$list = $preList | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq $fileType }
$list = $list | %{$_.FullName}
$hashedList=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
if ($hashedList.Length -gt 1)
{
    $hashedList.Clear()
}
foreach ($i in $list)
{
    $hashedList+=Get-FileHash $i
}
[int]$iterator1=0
foreach ($i in $hashedList)
{
    [int]$iterator2=0
    foreach ($j in $hashedList)
    {
        if(($i.Hash -eq $j.Hash) -and ($iterator2 -gt $iterator1))
        {
            if(Test-Path $j.Path)
            {
                $checkFile=Split-Path $j.Path -Leaf
                $rnd=(Get-ChildItem $j.Path).CreationTime
                $rnd=$rnd -Replace("/","-")
                $checkFile="$rnd$fileType"
                $dirPath=$mkdups
                $j.Path="$dirPath\$checkFile"
                $src=$i.Path
                $dest=$j.Path
                Move-Item -Path $src -Destination $dest #Problem Area
            }
        }
        $iterator2++
    }
    $iterator1++
}
```

Comment: just to cover the obvious: have you checked the value of `$dest` before the move? Does it contain a valid path?

Comment: I have. $dest contains a file path like in the written out example - D:\Pictures\Duplicates\5-6-2015 06:34:22PM.bmp. Thanks for checking that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use colons in filenames.

use something like `$dest.Replace(':','_')` to replace them with underscores.

Comment: I can't believe that was it! I feel like such a nincompoop. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Mike Shepard is right, the issue is that you have colons in your file name, and that's not allowed. But I'm writing to help you in another way...

Nesting your `ForEach($j in $hashedList)` within `ForEach($i in $hashedList)` hurts my brain too much to not comment. I also see If/ElseIf/ElseIf/ElseIf/ElseIf which is better done with the `Switch` cmdlet. Also, re-creating an array for hashes after you already have one for the files, well, just no. Lastly, doing a recursive file listing, and then filtering out the files that you want is a waste. Provide a filter to the provider so that it only returns the files that you want to deal with instead of everything, and then making PowerShell filter out the extra files. The provider does one thing, it deals with files and their information, and it does it better than PowerShell can (usually) so filtering at that level is preferred. Here, consider these alternatives:

Let me introduce you to `Switch`. No, not the song by Will Smith. This great little cmdlet will let you define various cases, and will execute code accordingly. Check out what we can reduce your If/ElseIf block to:

```psh
while ($workingType -eq "false")
{
    Switch(Read-Host){
        "1" {$fileType = "*.jpg";$workingType = 'true';Continue} 
        "2" {$fileType = "*.avi";$workingType = 'true';Continue}  
        "3" {$fileType = "*.gif";$workingType = 'true';Continue}
        "4" {$fileType = "*.png";$workingType = 'true';Continue}
        "5" {
            "Okay then, Mr. 'I'm special and deserve my own type', enter your custom type."
            $fileType = Read-Host "[Example: *.bat]"
            $workingType = 'true'
            Continue
            }
        default {"This is an invalid option. Try again."}
    }
}
```

That also sets us up for my next point by setting `$fileType` to something like `"*.jpg"` instead of just `"jpg"`.

Instead of getting all files, get just the ones you want by using the `-filter` parameter. That will pass the filter directly to the FileSystem provider, so it only returns the files that you want. No more `$prelist` and all that junk:

```psh
$List = Get-ChildItem "$DIR" -Filter $fileType -Recurse
```

Now that you have a list of the files that you want to look at, rather than turning it into just a list of their paths, leave them as [FileInfo] objects, it's way more useful! We can just add the Hash directly to each object as a property as such:

```psh
$List | ForEach{Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Hash' -NotePropertyValue (Get-FileHash $_.FullName | Select -Expand Hash)}
```

There, now all the files have their Hash included on their object. Now the magic... not nesting `ForEach` loops inside eachother. That practice gets exponentially long depending on how many objects you have in your list. Instead, use `Group-Object` on the `Hash` property. Then filter out any where there's only one file in the group, and you've got your duplicates!

```psh
$List | Group Hash | Where{$_.Count -gt 1}
```

That shows you all of your duplicates split up by file hash. It returns grouping objects, that have a `Count` property, which is self explanatory, a `Name` property, which is the value of whatever you grouped by (in your case, each hash value), and a `Group` property, which is a collection of all of the things that match that `Name`. So from there you move files from each group, skipping the first one. Something like:

```psh
$List | Group Hash | Where{$_.Count -gt 1} | ForEach{
    $_.Group | Select -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Dest $mkdups
}
```

That right there replaces your entire `ForEach($i in $hashlist)` loop and everything in it. So let's put that all together now:

```psh
cls
"Duplicate Sorter -- Version 1.0.0 Alpha"
"-------------------------------------"
"What directory do you want to sort?"
$workingDir = "false"
#Loop until they choose a valid directory
while ($workingDir -eq "false")
{
    $DIR = Read-Host
    if ($DIR -match "C:\\$|C:\\Program Files|C:\\Program Files(x86)|C:\\Windows|C:\\DRIVERS|C:\\SWTOOLS|C:\\inetpub|C:\\PerfLogs")
    {
        "You can't choose that directory. Choose a different one."   
    } 
    Else
    {
        $workingDir = "true"
    }
}

#List, then loop until they choose a file type
"What file type do you want to sort? (Press the relative number)"
"1. Pictures"
"2. Movies"
"3. GIFs"
"4. PNGs"
"5. Custom Type"
$workingType = "false"
while ($workingType -eq "false")
{
    Switch(Read-Host){
        "1" {$fileType = "*.jpg";$workingType = 'true';Continue} 
        "2" {$fileType = "*.avi";$workingType = 'true';Continue}  
        "3" {$fileType = "*.gif";$workingType = 'true';Continue}
        "4" {$fileType = "*.png";$workingType = 'true';Continue}
        "5" {
            "Okay then, Mr. 'I'm special and deserve my own type', enter your custom type."
            $fileType = Read-Host "[Example: *.bat]"
            $workingType = 'true'
            Continue
            }
        default {"This is an invalid option. Try again."}
    }
}

#Get a list of all files to look at based on selections
$List = Get-ChildItem "$DIR" -Filter $fileType -Recurse

#Add each file's Hash to it's object
$List | ForEach{Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Hash' -NotePropertyValue (Get-FileHash $_.FullName | Select -Expand Hash)}

#Create backup folder if it's not there
$mkdups = "$DIR\$fileType Duplicates"
if (!(Test-Path -Path $mkdups))
{
    New-Item $mkdups -ItemType directory  
}

#Move duplicates, skipping the first file of any set of duplicates
$List | Group Hash | Where{$_.Count -gt 1} | ForEach{$_.Group | Select -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Dest $mkdups}
```

For an explanation of what I did to validate the directory, see: https://regex101.com/r/jB0yD9/1